# Export from the hash table to csv results in empty values

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

Everything works as expected except for the Path section of the csv file when I export the values.  They are blank.  Can anyone what is wrong with my code?

```
$ht = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $path = $file.FullName
    $lines = Get-Content $path
        foreach ($line in $lines) {
            if ($match = $ht | where {$_.line -EQ $line}) {
                 $match.count = $match.count + 1
                 $match.Paths += $path
            } else {
                     $ht += new-object PSObject -Property @{
                      Count = 1
                      Paths = @(,$path)
                      Line = $line }
    }
}
}

$ht
$ht.GetEnumerator() | select Count, Paths, Line | Export-Csv c:\NLG_GPO_Sort.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object property is named Paths. You select Path. Change it to match.

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | select Count, Paths, Line | Export-Csv c:\NLG_GPO_Sort.csv
```

Comment: When I try this, the only thing that shows up is     System.Object[]

Comment: Please edit your post to show the code that you are actually running now.